# On initial login, running applications do not show in the unity launcher or ALT+TAB

Tags: unity, 16.04, launcher

This problem is fixed if I log out and log back in again, but comes back if I reboot the computer.  I have recorded a video showing the problem:

http://173.72.189.135/bug.mkv

Thanks in advance for any help